# Spring 4 RestController Dispatcher url-pattern

Tags: java, spring

I have an annotated rest controller, like the one below.  I'm able to get the services to host fine, but only if I configure the full path for each individual service in web.xml:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/")
public class StuffRestController
{
    @RequestMapping("/getStuffList")
    public List<Stuff> getStuffList() { 
      ... make stuff ...
      return stuffList;
    }

    ... many other similar services ...
}
```

This is really the only spring resource in my application; although, we are using spring security.

The below are the only lines spring4-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.stuff.presentation.controller" />  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.stuff.security" />
```

The StuffRestController class resides in the "...controller" package.

web.xml:

```
 <servlet>    
  <servlet-name>spring4</servlet-name>    
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring4-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>    
  <servlet-name>spring4</servlet-name>    
  <url-pattern>/service/getStuffList</url-pattern>   
 </servlet-mapping>
```

All of the above actually all works fine and dandy, but there are 30 other services in this controller and I would rather not make a new servlet mapping for every method.  The issue occurs when I attempt to "wildcard" the mapping.  I've tried /service/**, /service**, and /service/*.  And many other combinations.

Most all simply don't map properly, and I receive 404 errors.  If I use /service/* it will engage the dispatcher servlet when /service/getStuffList is called, but it responds with:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/service/getStuffList] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring4'
```

I'm sure this is something simple with how URL mappings are created, but it is eluding me.

Comment: What is the URL you're hitting?

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/service/getStuffList"  ...which works fine if I have the web.xml configured like I do in the post, but I'd prefer to have a catch all URL pattern for everything /service/ and lower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you've included the path: `/service/getStuffList` in both your `DispatcherServlet` and the `@RestController` request mapping. So to access the rest controller method, you've to hit the following URL:

```
{contextPath}/service/getStuffList/service/getStuffList
```

So, either change the dispatcher servlet url-pattern to `/`, so it will handle every request coming to your application, and then based on path after `myApp`, will redirect to appropriate controller. Or, set the `RestController` mapping to `/*`. You should prefer the former approach.

If you want to have your servlet handle request coming at `/service`, then change the url-pattern to `/service/*`. But then you've to remove all the request mapping from class level. Else at current scenario, you've to hit the following url:

```
{contextPath}/service/service/getStuffList
```

However, if you want to include the dispatcher servlet url-pattern in path resolution (i.e., you want to map the class at `/service` and also map servlet to that path), you can set `alwaysUseFullPath` property to `true` of URL handler mapping. For that, add the following to your spring context xml file:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name = "alwaysUseFullPath" value = "true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you sir... I had a misunderstanding of how the mapping interacted with the annotations.  Your answer lead me to the conclusion.  Using "/" as not really an option with this app, we are merely adding spring for the use of @RestController.  I changed my mapping to <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>, and [host]/[context]/spring/service/getStuffList responds as I expect now.

Comment: @slambeth You're welcome. BTW, you can also map it to `/service/*` and set the property as I quoted in my answer, and just use `/service/getStuffList`.